# IE 11 - F12 Dev Tools - how to set "user agent string" automatically for an IE session

Tags: internet-explorer, agent, emulation

**We'd like to be able to change the "user string text" field of F12 tools emulation, so that IE11 would behave like IE 10 for a certain purpose that currently works as IE10 but not as IE11.**

**We'd like such change to be valid for the whole IE session, and that when IE is fully closed, opening IE again will get it up in regular IE11 (no emulation).**

Maybe from some command line, or other trick. That would simplify the user's work, and eliminate the need to manually : click F12, goto Emulation tab, change the value, change F12 tools sub screen below to a separate window, and get to work with the emulated IE.

Thank u

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could set the FEATURE_BROWSER_EMULATION FCK to 10001 for iexplore.exe, but you would need to remove that FCK after the session closes. Otherwise you'll leave IE in a pretty bad state.

See the documentation [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee330730(v=vs.85).aspx).